# What is R in <R>(observer: Observer<R>) => Subscription | Function | void

Tags: typescript, observers, typescript-generics

The Angularfire2 project has a work-in-progress branch adding a storage feature. Two new files include an Observable class and a Factory function.

Observable class

```
export class FirebaseUploadTaskObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {

  constructor(
    subscribe?: <R>(observer: Observer<R>) => Subscription | Function | void, 
    public uploadTask?:firebase.storage.UploadTask) {
      super(subscribe);
  }

  lift<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R> {
    const observable = new FirebaseUploadTaskObservable<R>();
    observable.source = this;
    observable.operator = operator;
    observable.uploadTask = this.uploadTask;
    return observable;
  }
  ...
}
```

Factory function

```
export function FirebaseUploadTaskFactory (uploadTask: UploadTask):
  FirebaseUploadTaskObservable<UploadTaskSnapshot> {

  const obsFunction = (obs: Observer<UploadTaskSnapshot>) => { ... };

  const objectObservable = new FirebaseUploadTaskObservable(obsFunction, uploadTask);

  ...
}
```

In short, error I'm getting is:

> Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928041/use-of-classname-syntax/42930159#42930159) helped reinforce what I think I already knew about `<T>` and generics in Typescript, but what is `<R>`?

(Full error message)

> Argument of type '(obs: Observer) => void' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '((observer: Observer) => void |
>   Function | Subscription) | undefined'. Type '(obs:
>   Observer) => void' is not assignable to type
>   '(observer: Observer) => void | Function | Subscription'. Types
>   of parameters 'obs' and 'observer' are incompatible. Type
>   'Observer' is not assignable to type
>   'Observer'. Type 'R' is not assignable to type
>   'UploadTaskSnapshot'.

Comment: @Shaun not sure why you deleted your comment and answer (it was the better explanation, honestly). To respond to your deleted comment, I edited the question after getting answers because Asad's response suggested my question was missing relevant details. I added the `lift()` method to give context to why just replacing `<T>` with `<R>` isn't correct.

Comment: The update to the question confirms that the correct solution is to remove the unnecessary `R` parameter and use `(observer: Subscriber<T>)` instead of `<R>(observer: Subscriber<R>)`. The `<T` parameter in `lift<T, R>`  is unnecessary as well, but that is a different topic. The `R` in `lift` is a totally separate type variable and isn't affected in any way by the problem you're having or the fix for it.

Comment: @stealththeninja I deleted my comment, because I felt uncertain about the feedback it was giving you. I deleted my answer, because I concluded that it was not relevant to the specific problem you were facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, `<R>(observer: Observer<R>) => Subscription | Function | void` means:

> for any type R, a function that can turn an Observer of R into a Subscription or a function or a nothing

Now, your constructor has signature `constructor(subscribe?: <R>(...`. This means it is *demanding* a function with the properties stated above, i.e. it demands a function that will be happy with an observer of any kind whatsoever. As an example, this constructor will not be satisfied with a:

```
const obsFunction = (obs: Observer<UploadTaskSnapshot>) => { ... }
```

Which in English is a:

> function that takes an `Observer<UploadTaskSnapshot>` and returns something

because it isn't a function that will take an observer of R for *any type R* and like it. This function has a peculiar taste in observers that the constructor is not equipped to accommodate.

The other answers provide some indication of how to fix the issue, but I believe your `<R>` parameter might be redundant here. You might just want `(observer: Observer<T>)`.

Comment: It would be tempting to simply use `(observer: Observer<T>)`, but another method inside the Observable class works with `Operator<T, R>`. In keeping the example simple, I didn't include the `lift()` method but can still add it if it helps clarify the question: https://github.com/littleninja/angularfire2/blob/storage/src/storage/firebase_upload_task_observable.ts#L13

Comment: @stealththeninja It seems that codebase is suffering from the [same bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593) rxjs itself was suffering from; the `T` in `lift<T, R>` is redundant. An `Observable<T>` need implement a `lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>`. Note that the `T` is dictated by the type of observable you have, not the caller of `lift`. E.g. if you have an `Observable<number>`, the caller shouldn't just be able to provide an `Operator<"potato", Date>`, as would be legal with a method `lift<T, R>`.

Comment: Since opening this question, rxjs had resolved the issue in 5.4.2 and angularfire2 moved its dependency to 5.5.2. Accepting this answer as I think it provides the best answer to the question about generic type "peculiarities" specific to the rxjs classes seen here. :) Thank you for the time and patience in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`<T>` and `<R>` in this case are examples of using [*generics*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in TypeScripts.

Quick summary of generics.  You can declare an interface/class/function with a *generic type parameters* like so:

```
class List<T> {
  getItem(position: number): T { ... }
  addItem(item: T): void { ... }
}
```

Then you can use it *generically* by specifying the `T` when using it.  In this case we're saying we specify `T` be the type `User`:

```
let x = new List<User>(); // a list of Users;
x.addItem(myUser);  // we expect this to take an item of type User
x.getItem(0); // we expect this to return a number;
```

Comment: Your explanation speaks to what T is, but the question asks about R.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to TypeScript, what I learned from TypeScript generic is that  is just a type variable, we use T to capture type, not values.

for this question,  is another type variable, you can give any letters you want, but for this case, first, you have two type variables, so you need two different letters, second, why using letter R? because you want to say this type variable is a request type, just like you using T to say this type variable is a type